# Como buscar un carácter especial "_" utilizando LIKE en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy empezando en todo esto y me dejaron una actividad utilizando LIKE en MySQL, donde debo encontrar los datos que contengan _20, como _ es un carácter reservado, no lo detecta. Estuve investigando y algunas paginas mencionan que puedo usar:

```
WHERE codigoProducto LIKE '%`_`20%'; o WHERE codigoProducto LIKE '%[_]20%';
```

Pero no me funciona.
Este fue el link donde lei eso 
https://www.ionos.mx/ayuda/hosting/usar-una-base-de-datos-mysql-para-proyectos-web/palabras-reservadas-en-mysql-57-reserved-words/
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703637/escaping-special-characters-in-a-sql-like-statement-using-sql-parameters

Así es el código completo:

```
USE ventas;
SELECT codigoProducto, productoNombre
FROM productos
WHERE codigoProducto LIKE "%_20%";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En MySQL, para hacer un escape de ese carácter especial debe utilizar un backslash (\). La sentencia SQL debería ser la siguiente:

```sql
USE ventas;
SELECT codigoProducto, productoNombre
FROM productos
WHERE codigoProducto LIKE "%\_20%";
```

- Pregunta similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167132/mysql-like-query-with-underscore/22167148

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó perfecto! :D

Answer (score 0):

USE ventas;
SELECT codigoProducto, productoNombre
FROM productos
WHERE codigoProducto LIKE "%!_20%" escape "!";

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo esta consulta responde a la pregunta, además de darle el formato correspondiente. Lee [answer].